# What is the correct start up sequence of ATG instances?

Tags: atg, oracle-commerce

Is the below ATG instance startup sequence correct?

1. Lock instances (primary followed by secondary)
2. Process editor and global scenario server instances
3. Customer facing store instances
4. CSC instances
5. Search instances
6. Publishing instances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lock instances (primary followed by secondary)

Process editor and global scenario server instances

Customer facing store instances (Page Servers)

CSC instances (Agent)

Staging instance

Search instances

Publishing instances